# how to make an PHP webhook server

Tags: php, webhooks

I need to make a webhook server from where I can send json data to different receivers/clients.
How can I build it up using PHP?

What methods should I use to send json data?

Comment: It is not really clear what you ask about here. What is your concrete programming problem making such a server? What have you tried so far? Also there is no special PHP method to send Json data, if you refer to the HTTP method, it depends, normally it is an response to either GET or POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shuld have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

[Send json post using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php)

[php://input <> $_POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703906/php-input-post)